# VS post build event command line equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: build, intellij-idea

Is there an equivalent in IDEA? This can obviously be achieved with an Ant script, but I wonder if there's something build in into IDEA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [works via Ant](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-triggers-for-ant-build-target.html). Right click on the target in the Ant Panel and specify the condition (After Compilation).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, this is a 'no', at least for IntelliJ 10.5

IntelliJ integrates with Ant, and Ant can do build events, but IntelliJ only lets you configure Ant tasks to run before or after run or compile (as mentioned in the accepted answer), which is a very limited subset of build events.

Like if you want to copy the output file to a shared area after compilation of target X (a typical post-build event for me), you can't set that up in IntelliJ specifically, you have to add this to the Ant target description for X after the 'jar' command:

`<copy file="${artifact.output.yourproject:jar}/JarFile.jar" todir="C:/Shared/JarArea/"/>`

Please educate me if I'm wrong.