# Is there post-build event in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, openjpa, post-build-event

Is there post-build event in IntelliJ IDEA (11 in my case) ? Oddly I couldn't find it via googling.

I want to perform binary enhancement for my OpenJPA entities before it builds output artifact.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802304/vs-post-build-event-command-line-equivalent-in-intellij-idea ?

Comment: Yep. You're right. I'm voting on closing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get enough votes to close :(

It works via Ant. Right click on the target in the Ant Panel and specify the condition (After Compilation).