# How to set up IDEA to execute post compilation task?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

When trying to run some code after compilation is finished, I wrote the following in my sbt build:

```
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile) map { x=>
    // post-compile work
    doFoo()
    x
}
```

Which works well if I run `sbt compile` from command line, but doesn't get executed when I build from IntelliJ IDEA.

Is there any way to have IntelliJ IDEA run my post compilation step?

Comment: I don't know the way to run that post compilation step, but in some cases as a workaround to get similar behavior you could use `Before launch` from `Run/Debug Configurations` when you can add among others a SBT task execution. See [SBT plugin documentation](https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin/wiki#run-configuration-settings).

Comment: I believe so, since I specify the version in build.properties. But regardless of the SBT version, it seems as if IDEA is not using the Compile step but something else instead

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way IntelliJ IDEA supports is via Ant, unfortunately.

See [VS post build event command line equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5802458/463761).

Also, if you go down this route, you might be interested to use [ant4sbt](https://github.com/sbt/ant4sbt).

Answer (score 0):

IDEA has Run/Debug configurations.

In the `Before Launch` option, normally we have `Make` as the default action.

It is a matter of simply adding a `Run external Tool` action after Make.  We can define any number of actions.

The external tool could invoke `SBT`.

Or we can remove `Make` and call `SBT` to handle all the process.  The only inconvenience of this, is that is a little less confortable to go to syntax errors when compiling.